# Syncing Many to many relationship in Event Listener (Laravel 5.7)

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eloquent-relationship

Laravel App has roles and each `Role` has permissions (many to many)

Each user has multiple roles (Many to many)

When the permissions of Role are changed/updated, Event `RolePermissionsChanged` is triggered and the listener has following code:

```
public function handle(RolePermissionsChanged $event)
{
     $role_permissions=$event->role()->permissions;
     foreach ($event->role()->users as $user) {
        $user->permissions()->sync($role_permissions);
      }
}
```

This has to update `permission_user` table to sync the roles to the user. When the event is triggered, the job fails with an error:

`Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sync does not exist.`

If I change the line in `foreach` loop to `App\User::find($user->id)->permissions()->sync($role_permissions);`, it is working but I know it should be done the other way. Can anyone guide where I am going wrong.

Edit:

Below is `RolePermissionsChanged::class`

```
<?php

namespace App\Events\Auth;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use App\Role;

class RolePermissionsChanged
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    public $role;

    public function __construct(Role $role)
    {
        $this->role=$role;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your `RolePermissionsChanged` class to your question?

Comment: @RossWilson, added.

Comment: Where is `$event->role()` coming from as I don't see a `role()` method in your `RolePermissionsChanged` class?

Comment: I think the issue is `$event->role()` will return a Collection instance whereas `foreach ($event->role->users as $user)` this should work.

Comment: It is being passed as an instance of `App\Role:class` as described in Laravel Documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#defining-listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$event->role()` should be `$event->role`, it's a public property defined in the event class, where `$event->role()` is treating it as a function call.

```
public function handle(RolePermissionsChanged $event)
{
    $permission_ids = $event->role->permissions->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $event->role->users->each(function (User $user) use ($permission_ids) {
        $user->permissions()->sync($permission_ids);
    });
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer. I think this should be accepted. just with a change: `$user->permissions->sync($permission_ids);`

Comment: thanks, yes this works with the edit. :) thanks both